# Replace values in R data frame according to values in other data frame

Tags: iterator, r

I would like to change row names values from a first data frame if these rows names are present in another data frame, and change it to a corresponding value (defined in the second data frame). I could do it with a `for` loop, but I wonder what would be some other more suitable ways to do it in R.

Here is a toy dataset (my real dataset has 10^5 rows):

```
df <- data.frame("sample_1" = rep(0,3), "sample_2" = rep(0,3), row.names = paste0('gene_', seq(1, 3)), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
annotation <- data.frame("gene" =  paste0('gene_', seq(1, 2)), 'name' = paste0('name_', seq(1, 2)), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
df$gene <- rownames(df)
```

Initial data frames:

```
df 
       sample_1 sample_2   gene
gene_1        0        0 gene_1
gene_2        0        0 gene_2
gene_3        0        0 gene_3

annotation
    gene   name
1 gene_1 name_1
2 gene_2 name_2
```

Solution found:

```
for (x in rownames(df)){
  if (x %in% annotation$gene){
    df[x,]$gene <- annotation$name[which(annotation$gene == x)]
  }
}
rownames(df) <- df$gene
df$gene <- NULL
```

Resulting data frame:

```
df
       sample_1 sample_2
name_1        0        0
name_2        0        0
gene_3        0        0
```

Answer (score 3):

#### Code Review

One change I would make to your solution is to directly modify the row names as below (instead of modifying `gene` and then setting the row names equal to `gene`).

```
for (i in 1:nrow(df)){
  if (rownames(df)[i] %in% annotation$gene) {

    rownames(df)[i] = annotation$name[which(annotation$gene == rownames(df)[i])]

  }
}
df$gene <- NULL

df
#        sample_1 sample_2
# name_1        0        0
# name_2        0        0
# gene_3        0        0
```

This solution is similar to the original, but iterates over row numbers (1-3 in this case) instead of row names. This allows direct modification of the row names and makes the code slightly more concise. This version doesn't use `gene` at all.

That's how I'd modify the existing solution, but overall I wouldn't use a `for` loop. `for` loops can be slow since they iterate over every element (and your data set has 10^5 rows). Below is another approach using the `dplyr` library.

#### Another Approach

```
library(dplyr)
library(tibble)

df <- left_join(df, annotation, by = "gene") %>%        # Join "annotation" and "df"
mutate(gene = if_else(is.na(name), gene, name)) %>%     # Convert "gene" to "name" when "name" is valid
column_to_rownames(var = "gene") %>%                    # Set row names to "gene"
select(-name)                                           # Remove "name"

df
#        sample_1 sample_2
# name_1        0        0
# name_2        0        0
# gene_3        0        0
```

This syntax may look unfamiliar but it's doing 3 main things:
  - left-joining `df` and `annotation` by the `gene` field. It has to be a left-join so all rows of `df` are preserved!
  - changing the value of `gene` to `name` only when `name` is non-null
- setting the row names equal to `gene`

The pipe operator `%>%` passes the data through these operations without needing to repeatedly type `df <-`. These are all vectorized operations and so are faster than a `for` loop, especially for large data sets.

`dplyr` syntax can be intimidating at first, but it's an extremely popular (and I believe intuitive) paradigm to manipulate data. [Here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/dplyr.html) is a handy intro on `dplyr` syntax.